# Page redirection without refresing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, redirect

I want redirection without refreshing the whole parent page. Is there any way through which I can perform this. I need the functionality like the site below

https://github.com/jquery/jquery

Like in the above site the listing of files are there under jQuery. When we click on any of the file it will redirect us to that file without page refresh.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML)

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1012986.aspx/1?How+to+Redirect+page+without+refresh OR mvc ajax in 3 and above `:)` +1 for undefined

Comment: @undefined : I know about it but how?

Comment: see this plugin www.asual.com/jquery/address/  but notes the url changes with slashes only on browsers that support this feature. IE9,8 doesn't therefore the plugin will use # with those

Comment: the above plugin does what you are looking for. simply it is an ajax and html5 history function. github using similar technique.

Comment: -1 for "look at this site, i want mine to be like this." if you are a programmer, you should exactly know what your goals, requirements are. The way you gave the example is justified for clients, not for developers.

Comment: @itachi : I've just explained my requirements through similar example just in case if anyone don't understand. there's nothing in my question to down vote. If you don't want to answer, don't disappoint someone either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your exact requirements, I cant give you a proper answer in general, jQuery will be your best bet.

Use jQuery.ajax (doc here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

This method allows you to query data asynchronously without page refresh and then do what you want to the result.

If you give a exact description of your requirements, I could point to you a tutorial.

Comment: you can get the idea of my requirements by visiting the URL I've mentioned in my question. Basically, I need the functionality like whenever I click on the link, it should redirect me to the specified page without page refresh.

Comment: There is one thing you need to be clear.. You want to redirect to a different page or a part of the page in the main page itself? In the example you are giving, its a part of the page itself which is brought into view on click of the link. You can search for jQuery Ajax Slider and you will understand. If you really want some readymade components, you can also try jQuery UI